# php validation from array form

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a code like this

First looping count how many post the array:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $jumlah_qty ;$i++) {
    if(!empty($qty[$i]) && !empty($id_cat[$i])) {
```

Insert booking:

```
        $insert_booking_hd = $user_class->select($az);
        $id_cates = $id_cat[$i];
        for($b = 0;$b<$qty[$i];$b++) {
```

First validation if `$_POST[$id_cates)` is set run this code:

```
            if(isset($_POST[$id_cates."".$b])){
                $id_seat = $_POST[$id_cates."".$b];
```

Find the seat number in $select_seat and find if seat number is exist in $seat_number:

```
                $select_seat = $user_class->select($query);
                $seat_number = $user_class->select($querys);
                $row_seat = $user_class->numrows($select_seat);
                $row_seat2 = $user_class->numrows($seat_number);
                if($row_seat>0) {
                    $update_seat = $user_class->update($update_false);
                    $bol[$b] = FALSE;
                } else { 
                    if( $row_seat2>0 ) {
                        $insert_booking_dt = $user_class->insert($insert);
                        $update_seat = $user_class->update($update_true);
                        $bol[$b] = TRUE;
                    } else {
                        $bol[$b] = FALSE;
                    }
                }    
            } else {
                $insert_booking_dt = $user_class->insert($insert_without_seat);
                $bol[$b] = TRUE;
            }

            if($bol[$b]) {
                echo "FALSE";
                header("location:../../../print.php?id=$id_booking");
            }
            else {
                echo "WRONG";
                header("location:../../../event.php?msg=Same seat number");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Anything wrong with my php validation?

Because if I input array of `$id_seat` it will always redirect to print.php although validation is FALSE

for example if I input 3 array and then I echo FALSE WRONG FALSE FALSE

still redirect to print.php not to event.php

How can I read if one of array is get WRONG and then redirect to event.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > How can I read if **one** of array is get WRONG and then redirect to event.php?

You may `break` out of for-loops.

Instead of:

```
else {
    echo "WRONG";
    header("location:../../../event.php?msg=Same seat number");
}
```

You could try:

```
else {
    echo "WRONG";
    header("location:../../../event.php?msg=Same seat number");
    break 2;
}
```

Comment: @derylihs You are welcome. Btw, is `$bol` used after for loops? If so, then I should edit my answer.